How to find AZURE_ENDPOINT, AZURE_API_KEY, and KNOWLEDGE_BASE_ID in the latest Azure Portal?
I'm trying to set up a custom question-answering resource in Azure, but I'm having trouble locating the following details in the new Azure Portal interface:
AZURE_ENDPOINT: The endpoint URL for the custom question-answering resource.
AZURE_API_KEY: The API key associated with the resource.
KNOWLEDGE_BASE_ID: The ID for the knowledge base.

Most of the solutions I've found seem to be based on an older version of the Azure Portal, and the layout has changed since then. Could someone guide me on where to find these values in the latest Azure Dashboard?
Full Codes:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
require('dotenv').config();

const qnaEndpoint = {
  endpoint: 'URL',
  endpointKey: process.env.AZURE_API_KEY,
  knowledgeBaseId: process.env.KNOWLEDGE_BASE_ID
};

const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(qnaEndpoint);

exports.getAnswer = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const question = req.query.question || req.body.question;

  if (!question) {
    return res.status(400).send('Please provide a question.');
  }

  try {
    const result = await qnaMaker.getAnswers({ question: question });
    if (result && result.length > 0) {
      return res.status(200).json({ answer: result[0].answer });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ answer: 'No answer found.' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching answer:', error);
    return res.status(500).send('Error occurred while fetching answer.');
  }
});



Most of the solutions I've found seem to be based on an older version of the Azure Portal, and the layout has changed since then. Could someone guide me on where to find these values in the latest Azure Dashboard?



Go to Azure Portal. Navigate to Azure AI services resource (previously known as QnA Maker).



In the resource menu, select Overview you will find the Endpoint URL listed on the manage keys.


Use the below code for your requirement.
Code:
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Import necessary libraries
require("dotenv").config();
const {QnAMaker} = require("botbuilder-ai");

// Configure the QnA endpoint with environment variables
const qnaEndpoint = {
  endpoint: process.env.AZURE_ENDPOINT,
  endpointKey: process.env.AZURE_API_KEY,
  knowledgeBaseId: process.env.KNOWLEDGE_BASE_ID,
};

// Initialize QnAMaker with the endpoint configuration
const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(qnaEndpoint);

// Define and export the HTTP-triggered function
exports.getAnswer = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  // Extract question from query parameters or request body
  const question = request.query.question || request.body.question;

  // Check if a question was provided
  if (!question) {
    return response.status(400).send("Please provide a question.");
  }

  try {
    // Call QnA Maker to get answers
    const result = await qnaMaker.getAnswers({question: question});

    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    // If answers are found, send the first one; otherwise, inform that no answer was found
    if (result && result.length > 0) {
      return response.status(200).json({answer: result[0].answer});
    } else {
      return response.status(200).json({answer: "No answer found."});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Log and return error message in case of failure
    logger.error("Error fetching answer:", error);
    return response.status(500).send("Error occurred while fetching answer.");
  }
});

Logged In to Firebase.


You can get the knowledge base URL in the language project for that you need to login to the Azure AI Language Studio) here, navigate to the Deploy knowledge page.


